# How to get % of subtotal in Quicksight Pivot Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, pivot-table, amazon-quicksight, subtotal

I am creating a pivot table for leads a brokerage received in a county - I am trying to show the market share for each brokerage so I want to divide the leads a brokerage received by the total leads in the county. I was wondering if there is a way to divide based on the subtotal for each county.

Answer (score 1):

Add a calculated field called `Overall Leads Percentage` as follows:

```
sum(leads) / min(sumOver(leads, [], PRE_AGG))
```

You can then add this calculated field to the values field well of the pivot table. Also add the `brokerage` field to the column or row field well.

Finally filter your pivot table for the `county` you want to focus on.

Comment: That worked! Thank you @darcoli